# Insert data into specific Sqlite3 database row?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO User where User_name=(?) (user_name,user_password,user_wins,user_loses) VALUES(?,?,?,?)',(a,a,b,c,d))
self.connect.commit()
```

Logically i would have thought this would work but im not sure why it hasnt?
The first '?' in the sql statement is the same as 'a'.
I get this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error
```

So im wondering if it is actually possible to write to an already written row in a SQL database?

Comment: `INSERT` means add a completely new row. If you want to alter an existing row, you need `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` means add a completely new row. If you want to alter an existing row, you need `UPDATE`.

For instance

```sql
UPDATE User
SET user_password=?,
    user_wins=?,
    user_loses=?
WHERE user_name=?
```

passing the user name as the last variable.

So something like:

```
self.cursor.execute(
    'UPDATE User SET user_password=?, user_wins=?, user_loses=? WHERE user_name=?',
    (b,c,d,a)
)
```